# How can I write a fail-safe upstart script that starts an application with the necessary permissions?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, upstart

I'm planning on setting up a server using [Ubuntu Lucid Lynx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_10.04_LTS_.28Lucid_Lynx.29), which uses upstart. I'm not finding the documentation too intuitive, so I'd like to ask for a solution for my specific problem.

I'm currently using a script to start up my [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) tunnel with [Freenet6/gogo6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IPv6_tunnel_brokers#Worldwide) - right now it's a simple script invoking a single command, and its configuration file:

```
 #! /bin/sh
/usr/local/gw6c/bin/gw6c -f /usr/local/gw6c/bin/gw6c.conf
```

Of course, when this goes down, it tends to be silent, and so I'd need to get in and restart it.

I'd like to set up an upstart script which will

1. start this application on startup, functionally identical to the script I have
2. restart this script as 'root' should the application fail
3. enable me to restart the tunnel should anything go wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below script works on upstart on Ubuntu Lucid Lynx alpha 3

```
respawn
console none

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on [!12345]

script
chdir /usr/local/gw6c/bin/
exec /usr/local/gw6c/bin/gw6c 
end script
```